# How can I query a database with LINQ when the column is a number but I have a string in the WHERE?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using this code:

```
query = String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.PhraseNum) ?
               query :
               query.Where(w => w.PhraseNum == Convert.ToInt32(options.PhraseNum));
```

However I get an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there a way I can do this in LINQ and if not how can I convert outside of this and have the conversion not cause an exception if the string is not null?

Comment: Just convert string to int outside of query itself.

Comment: Is there a way that will do this even if the string is null? I want to avoid an exception.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(string)` doesn't throw an exception if the string is null. It returns 0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Alan2 in this case, it's better to use `if..else` instead of using `?:`

Comment: First check for null, then convert (or you can use int.TryParse but that is not the same), then add Where to your query.

Comment: Using the ternery operator here is a bit smelly anyway, an `if` statement would be nicer.

Comment: Can anyone give examples so I can accept.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only modify `query` if the string can be parsed to an `int`, which is an implicit check if it isn't null or empty:

```
if (int.TryParse(options.PhraseNum, out var phraseNum))
{
    query = query.Where(w => w.PhraseNum == phraseNum);
}
```

Before C# 7 the syntax was

```
int phraseNum;
if (int.TryParse(options.PhraseNum, out phraseNum))
etc.
```

Comment: @MotKohn Thanks, good to mention that. Not everybody is on the latest C# version yet, so I tend to be a bit conservative :)

Comment: I thought my edit would be a suggestion. Didn't realise I've gotten permission to do direct edits.

Comment: @Allrameest Even suggestions should be made with confidence :) But I'm OK.

Comment: No need for the `IsNullOrEmpty` since `TryParse` will return false in  those cases.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like LINQ is trying to evaluate the expression `Convert.ToInt32(options.PhraseNum)` on the server side as part of the WHERE clause.

Redo the code so that the variable is cast explicitly on the client-side outside the query expression:

```
Int32 phrase_num = String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.PhraseNum) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32;
query = String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.PhraseNum) ? query : query.Where(w => w.PhraseNum == phrase_num);
```

Or for a tidier approach overall:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.PhraseNum))
{
    Int32 phrase_num = Convert.ToInt32(options.PhraseNum);
    query = query.Where(w => w.PhraseNum == phrase_num);
}
```

I think that should resolve the problem and preserve the intended program logic.

EDIT: I'd endorse Gert Arnold's approach above if you are using the latest C# version, where out parameters can be declared inline in the TryParse method call itself.